# Core Data to-one relationship returns NULL

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject, relationships

The Batting.team relationship doesn't always save properly and returns null sometimes

[image]

About 100 'Team' NSManagedObjects are saved and can log their attributes as expected.  Then about 15000 'Batting' NSManagedObjects are saved and all attributes log correctly except for the relationship.

I want the Batting.team relationship to point to the Team object which has the same Team.teamID value as the Batting.teamID.

When setting the Batting relationship, I create a predicate to search for a specific Team.teamID, fetch the request and supposedly set that Team object to equal my Batting.team relationship.  Sometimes the relationship attribute gets set but most times it doesn't and I can't figure this out

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    NSError *error;

    NSString* dataPath_TEAMS = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"teams" ofType:@"json"];
    NSArray* TEAMS = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath_TEAMS] options:kNilOptions error:&error];   

    NSString* dataPath_ABC = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"abc" ofType:@"json"];
    NSArray* BATTING_ABC = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath_ABC] options:kNilOptions error:&error];



    //insert Team objects
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestTeams = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entityTeams = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Team" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequestTeams setEntity:entityTeams];

    for (id t in TEAMS) {
        Team *team = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Team" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        team.name       = [t objectForKey:@"name"];
        team.minYearID  = [t objectForKey:@"minYearID"];
        team.maxYearID  = [t objectForKey:@"maxYearID"];
        team.teamID     = [t objectForKey:@"teamID"];

        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
    NSArray *fetchedObjectsTeams = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestTeams error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Number of records in teams.json - %d", (int)[fetchedObjectsTeams count]);


    //insert Batting objects
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestBatting = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entityBatting = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Batting" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequestBatting setEntity:entityBatting];

    for (id b in BATTING_ABC) {
        Batting *batting = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Batting" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        batting.playerID    = [b objectForKey:@"playerID"];
        batting.h           = [b objectForKey:@"h"];
        batting.ab          = [b objectForKey:@"ab"];
        batting.hr          = [b objectForKey:@"hr"];
        batting.rbi         = [b objectForKey:@"rbi"];
        batting.sb          = [b objectForKey:@"sb"];
        batting.r           = [b objectForKey:@"r"];
        batting.bb          = [b objectForKey:@"bb"];
        batting.so          = [b objectForKey:@"so"];
        batting.yearID      = [b objectForKey:@"yearID"];
        batting.teamID      = [b objectForKey:@"teamID"];

        NSPredicate *teamIDPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"teamID == %@", [b objectForKey:@"teamID"]];
        [fetchRequestTeams setPredicate:teamIDPredicate];
        NSArray *fetchedSpecificTeam = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestTeams error:&error];

        batting.team = [fetchedSpecificTeam firstObject];

        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }

    fetchedObjectsBatting = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestBatting error:&error];
    for (Batting *b in fetchedObjectsBatting) {
        NSLog(@"playerID:   %@", b.playerID);
        NSLog(@"yearID:     %@", b.yearID);
        NSLog(@"teamID:     %@", b.teamID);
        NSLog(@"team:       %@\n\n", b.team.name);
    }

    return YES;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the screenshot of your model, it is configured so that each `Team` can have only one `Batting`.  Each time you set `batting.team` to a given `Team`, CoreData will remove the link from that `Team` to its current Batting object (thereby setting that `Batting` object's `team` to nil).

You should define the `Team` entity's `batting` relationship to be "to-Many" (each `Team` can have many `Battings`) using the Data Model inspector on the right hand side when in the model editor:

[image]